# JS updated displayed value different from DOM value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a list of three input boxes:
 - 1: type range [id: 29-range ; For: amount29]
 - 2: type text [id: 29; For: rangeInput29]
 - 3: type text [class: PreisSumme, id: preis29]

All three are "linked / updated"  by onclick events, so that the same value will be displayed on all of them (well Box three is a multiplication based on the value of box 1 / 2). This works without any problems.

In addition I have a function "calctotal" which runs through all the textboxes (with class: PreisSumme) and calculates the sum of the values. In general this works too.

Problem: The values extracted by the function calctotal uses the "old" values defined on pageload and not the ones updated by the user.

```js
function calctotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.PreisSumme').each(function(i, e) {
    console.log(e);
    var max = $(e).attr('value');
    total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(max);
    console.log(max);
  });
  console.log(total);
  document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(total);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='29-range' value=3 for='amount29' oninput='amount29.value=rangeInput29.value ; preis29.value=rangeInput29.value* PreisProd29 ; calctotal();' type='range' min='0' max='25' name='rangeInput29' />

<input id='29' style='width: 4em;' type='text' value='3' name='amount29' for='rangeInput29' oninput='rangeInput29.value=amount29.value ; preis29.value=amount29.value * 2; calctotal();' />

<input class='PreisSumme' style='width:5em;' id='preis29' for='preis29' value='1' disabled/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading attribute `value` while you should read property `value`. So instead of `.attr('value')` it could be `.prop('value')` but of course for form fields you should just use [$.fn.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var max = $(e).val();
```

There is a difference between attributes and properties. In this case attribute is not going to be updated why you change input value. Thus `value` attribute holds value it was initialized with (`defaultValue` property).